# What is this bush/plant?

Tags: identification

I want to buy more of these but don't know what it is.  It's one of only two plants that grow year round with flowers here in our flower bed in northern CA.  It's pretty hardy and doesn't need much water.  Hope someone can id it.
Thanks, Jim

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Euryops - there are three common varieties, E. acraeus, E. chrysanthemoides and E. pectinatus. It's impossible to get a clear image of the flowers and leaves in close up from the photo you've posted, even under magnification, so I'm unable to decide which one it is - you can either post another picture in close up, or check out the three different varieties for yourself.

Here's a link to E. pectinatus for comparison purposes https://www.smgrowers.com/products/plants/plantdisplay.asp?plant_id=624